# jquery scrollTo nth child

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, scroll

If I had two sets of classes, like so

```
<div class = "link 1"></div>
<div class = "link 2"></div>
<div class = "link 3"></div>
....
<div class = "link x"></div>
```

and

```
<div class = "target 1"></div>
<div class = "target 2"></div>
<div class = "target 3"></div>
....
<div class = "target x"></div>
```

how can i get the nth `link` to scroll the page to the nth `target` using jQuery `scrollTo`?
The classes 1, 2, 3.... are dynamically generated.

Thanks.

Comment: When each node uses a different identifier, semantically you should really be using `id`, not `class`. `class` is for groups of elements that share similar properties. `id` is for identification of an individual node, which is what you're doing with `class`.

Comment: I disagree...the divs with similar class in this case shares similar properties.

Comment: yes i know, this is not the "full" code. it has set of other generated classes and ids as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it based off [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), something like this:

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
   var target = $("div.target").eq($(this).index("div.link"));
   $.scrollTo(target);
});
```

This uses the [`.index(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) overload to get which link we clicked on, then it gets the same index of the `div.target` set to find the destination using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

*Note:* if there are *other* `<div>` elements with the classes `target` or `link` you need to tweak the selectors here so they're *only* searching the batch you're in, otherwise the indexes may be off.